# Counting number of comparisions in Insertion Sort

Tags: c++, sorting, insertion-sort

How can I change this implementation of the insertion sort code so that it also counts the number of comparisons performed during sorting and the number of array assignments(the number of times elements are exchanged)?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void insertionSort(int arr[], int length);
void printArray(int array[], int size);

int main()
{
    int array[] = {6,2,7,9,3,8,3,10};
    insertionSort(array, (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))-1);
    printArray(array, (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])) - 1);
    return 0;
}

void insertionSort(int arr[], int length)
{
int i, j, tmp;
for (i = 1; i < length; i++) {
    j = i;
    while (j > 0 && arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
        tmp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
        arr[j - 1] = tmp;
        j--;
        }
    }
}

void printArray(int array[], int size)
{
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        std::cout << array[j] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: By incrementing a counter where appropriate or [reading about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) online.

Comment: Algorithm Designs Course Assignment? Step through the code and see where it does that.

Comment: @FirstStep Yes. I tried incrementing a counter, swap++, just before the end of the while loop to count the number of elements. It returns 9, which I believe, according to my calculations, is the correct number of swaps required to swap the given array. However, I tried it with different arrays and I'm getting numbers which I believe to be wrong.

Comment: @JoeDoe - you also need to increment a compare counter after the while loop if j > 0.

Comment: @rcgldr I believe that counter would count the number of comparisions performed while the array is sorted? Also, is my method of counting the number of array assignments correct?

Comment: @JoeDoe - yes, it would count the number of compares that didn't involve a swap. The number of swaps plus that count for non swap compares would be the total number of compares.